# Mocking `peer` while unit testing gRPC with bufconn

Tags: unit-testing, go, grpc-go, go-testing

I have unidirectional (both client- and server-) streaming gRPC methods implemented in my golang server. I came across [`bufconn`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.37.0/test/bufconn) which enables me to creates my server via in-memory connections in my tests. However, I have logic in my method where I check the peer's address, it always returns "bufconn". I do rely on the peer to provide the IP address along with its port, but I can't really achieve that using bufconn.

1. What is a canonical (or preferred) way to test gRPC streaming calls in golang?
2. Is it considered an anti-pattern to rely on peer information in the context?

Comment: Can you just make up the addresses for testing? Your questions about testing streaming RPCs seem unrelated to using bufconn (streaming RPCs work fine over bufconn).

Comment: @jdizzle

Yeah - streaming is unrelated, but just wanted to give broader context (and didn't know if bufconn was still the right way to test streaming RPCs).

I did tried to make up an address like this:

```
 p := &peer.Peer{
  Addr: &net.TCPAddr{
   IP:   net.IPv4(1, 2, 3, 4),
   Port: 8888,
  },
 }
 ctx := peer.NewContext(context.Background(), p)
```

but bufconn just returns `"bufconn"` no matter what: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/test/bufconn/bufconn.go#L308

Comment: You’ll have to hook in your own mechanism for getting the IP address under testing (create a custom XGetter interface that takes the connection?)

Comment: I see where you're going with it. As a golang newbie, may I ask you a quick snippet what it would look like?

Comment: i'm not sure what the code looks like now for getting the peer address.  Maybe if you post it I can make some suggestions